# dovecot unable to start due to address already in use

Tags: linux, dovecot

I upgraded my Linux kernel and dovecot failed to start with the following error messages:

```
Error: service(managesieve-login): listen(*, 4190) failed: Address already in use
Error: service(pop3-login): listen(*, 110) failed: Address already in use
Error: service(pop3-login): listen(*, 995) failed: Address already in use
Error: service(imap-login): listen(*, 143) failed: Address already in use
Error: service(imap-login): listen(*, 993) failed: Address already in use
Fatal: Failed to start listeners
```

Strangely enough, I couldn't find any process bounded to those port numbers.  All commands below return nothing.

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep 110
# ss -tulpn |grep 110
# fuser 110/tcp
# lsof -i :110
```

I also tried to change the `listen` setting to my specific IP address and it still failed the same way.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?  Here's my version info:

```
# uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-26-222 4.14.177-107.254.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 7 18:30:14 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# dovecot --version
2.2.36 (1f10bfa63)
```

Comment: If I change the config to `listen = ::` then it starts fine.  So the problem is related to IPv4.  It's still unclear to me why it cannot bind to the IPv4 address though....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi it looks like you are using AWS as I am. I recently updated via Yum as well. I noticed that a new package named 'portreserve' was also installed. I killed that process, left the /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf as it was before and then started Dovecot successfully. I was also immediately able to reconnect my mail clients connection. I hope that helps you.

I also restarted the portreserve program since it seems useful to limit port access.

Comment: This is the exact problem that I'm having.  Thanks very much.  It's a life saver!

Comment: This worked for me, I wasted a whole day on this issue because I wasn't able to see what was running on the dovecot ports, tried everything and once i killed portreserve and restarted dovecot, it worked instantly. THANK YOU